# Horizontally flip a square area in screen and also horizontally flip Xaxis of mouse movements inside that square in Windows (its not a static square)

Tags: windows, screen, mouse, flip

Is it possible to get a square area flipped horizontally, I know this is kinda rare task, but its important, so, hope you could help me via any kind of software or script, thanks advanced...

I have a square area in the screen (perfect square) can I flip only that square area horizontally, leaving the rest of the screen the same, and at the same time whenever the mouse gets inside that square area, flip the mouse coordinates horizontally, so if I move the mouse to the right it goes to the left and viceversa, is that possible? I guess there is a catch in this task. Lets say I have a 100pix*100pix square in the middle of the screen that I want to invert the mouse movement whenever it gets inside it. when the mouse is in Left border of the screen and its moving to the Right and cross the Left boundary of the square, it inmediatly appears in the inner Right side of the square so if it is still moving to the Right the inverse effect will take it to the Left until it cross the Left boundary the square again so it appears inmediatly in the outer Right side of the square and continues to go to the Right side of the screen. Hope it make sence. I mean inside the 100pix*100pix in the X axis, the pixel 1 = pixel 100, pixel 2 = pixel 99, pixel 3 = pixel 98, and so on, I only want to inver the X axis. It is that possible? Thanks Advanced.

Answer (score 1):

I have never done this and it sounds like a bit of an odd request but I did find something that may assist you or it may not, but what I found is based in C#.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468815(v=vs.85).aspx

There is an option for SetCursor. So you would be able to obtain the current coordinates of the cursor and then invert them to force the mouse to move in the opposite direction. The challenge would be getting this to old be applied to the "square" that is defined.